# jquery :selected not working right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) for jQuery's `:selected` selector says that the proper way to use it is to use, e.g., `$('select').filter(':selected')`. However, I can't get it to work! It only works when I use something like `$('select :selected')`.

Here's a minimal example, along with [my jsFiddle implementation of it](http://jsfiddle.net/fdU83/4/):

the javascript:

```
function getLengths() {
    $("#dothis").text($("select").filter(":selected").length);
    $("#dothat").text($("select :selected").length);
}

$(function() {
    getLengths();
    $("select").change(getLengths);
});
```

the relevant html:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="true">one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
<div>
  <pre>$("select").filter(":selected").length = <span id="dothis"></span></pre>
  <pre>$("select :selected").length = <span id="dothat"></span></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter option elements, not select:

```
function getLengths() {
    $("#dothis").text($("option").filter(":selected").length);
    $("#dothat").text($("select :selected").length);
}

$(function() {
    getLengths();
    $("select").change(getLengths);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdU83/6/

Answer (score 0):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdU83/5/)

`:selected` is a filter on an `option`

You want to do this:

```
$("select option").filter(":selected")
```

Or even better...

```
$("select option:selected")
```